# How to retreive delta calendarView from ms graph expanded with extension?

Tags: microsoft-graph-calendar

is there any smart way to get delta events from ms graph with extension?

Standard delta query is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/delta?startdatetime=2018-12-16T19:40:53&enddatetime=2020-12-16T19:40:53
```

Standard query for events with extension is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/?$expand=extensions(%24filter%3did+eq+%27Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Com.XXX.YYY%27)
```

and I couldn't find in documentation way to merge it and query for delta with "$expand=extensions".

Simpliest way, which comes to my mind is to ask api for delta and then ask one by one for expanded view object, but it's causes lots ot queries :/

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Would love to be able to fetch extension data along with the delta calendar view